# Why do they leave a cookbook on Earth in "To Serve Man"?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-twilight-zone

This makes no sense except as some dark joke played on linguists. Did the story itself have an explanation, or was the story actually different, like humans steal the book or otherwise find it by accident?

Comment: If it's a proper cookbook like *The Joy of Cooking* it devotes a significant number of pages to the optimal selection and preparation of ingredients.  So you'd want to keep it on hand as a reference.

Comment: Assuming you are referring to the Serling story from the original series in 1962, it would seem to be a bit of alien hubris. They arrived, solved all of humanity's problems and left a book which they probably assumed humans either could never translate or not bother trying. (Spoiler) even as Patty does eventually succeed, it's too late anyway - humans have essentially willingly subjugated themselves to the Kanamits by the time she figures it out.

Comment: @AnthonyX: way better if the book was found -- why leave them any sort of book at all unless they actually are a sadistic species (which as eaters of fellow humanoids they may well be) who really WANTED humans to find out what was in store for them.

Comment: "To Serve Man" is just a dumb joke, an overblown set-up pun ("Feghoot"), not worth close examination.

Comment: @AnthonyX "To Serve Man" is not a "serling story", it's a silly short story by Damon Knight which has been adapted (I hear tell) to TV and maybe also to radio.

Comment: @user14111: You know, that's exactly what it is -- it was funnier when Simpsons parodied it and in fact, perhaps the eventual parody is the justification -- perhaps both Knight and Serling would have appreciated the Treehouse of Horror episode where the aliens genuinely have their feelings hurt by the suspicious humans (Lisa, as I recall, was the one who did this...)

Comment: @AnthonyX There's certainly hubris involved, but their motive for leaving the book could also be part of a hunters' system of honor by which the prey has to have some chance of escape. It's considered more "sporting" to shoot an animal than to poison it, for instance.

Comment: Here's hoping Disney/Pixar makes an adaptation - "To Serve Sheep"; where a flock of sheep plagued by wolves, gratefully accept help from humans.  The humans protect then from the wolves, build a shelter, feed them, and so on...  One rather suspicious fellow though, find a human book...

Comment: @BaardKopperud: one honestly wonders how much food animals understand of their eventual fate -- i believe it is more than we think. certainly cats and dogs understand things like what going to the vet means and show anxiety prior to it, like on the way there. i think cattle might even know what's in store once they are in the area where they will be killed. but it is sort of a stretch to think that cattle or sheep when being fattened have any idea why humans are being so nice to them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the [original story](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1950-11/page/n91/mode/2up) by Damon Knight, the copy of *To Serve Man* is stolen from the Kanamit embassy.

> I saw Grigori frequently from then on, and he kept me posted about his progress.  He was highly excited about a month after that first meeting; he said he'd got hold of a book of the Kanamit's and was trying to puzzle it out.  They wrote in ideographs, worse than Chinese, but he was determined to fathom it if it took him years.  He wanted my help.
>
> Well, I was interested in spite of myself, for I knew it would be a long job.  We spent some evenings together, working with material from Kanamit bulletin boards and so forth, and with the extremely limited English-Kanamit dictionary they issued to the staff.  My conscience bothered me about the stolen book, but gradually I became absorbed by the problem.  Languages are my field, after all.  I couldn't help being fascinated.

There aren't any further details about how Grigori (the deuteragonist) obtained the book, but he seems like a pretty crafty character.  In any case, one of the themes of the story is how quickly the human race falls completely under the power of the Kannmit aliens.

Comment: Well, there you go -- the original story really does deal with the silliness  introduced in the TZ episode. No idea why they could not have done something similar in that episode -- I guess Damon Knight chose not to complain so that he could get some other work on TZ and yet he did not, did he? Maybe he did complain and so a great writer managed to talk himself out of contributing further to Zone.

Comment: It's interesting to read the story with the foreknowledge of the ending.  You can see that all the things the Kanamit bestowed are designed to help mankind thrive, the same way we fertilize a field.

Comment: @MarkRansom: imagine some humans consider it a fair exchange -- an improved life and at the end (which probably happens sooner than one would like, if u know anything about the age of beef and lamb u humans like) u are presumably put to death painlessly. i am sure there would be many collaborators especially if they, ala the Cyclops in the Odyssey, were eaten last.

Comment: @releseabe the story was published in 1950, almost a decade before Twilight Zone existed.